# how to make loop within loop go back to first loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have the a program to print items from  lists within lists in a specific way. Here is that piece of code:

```
 for y in range(0,5):      
     print '\n'
     for x in tableau:
          if y < len(x):
           print x[y],
          else :
              print '   '
```

What I want is for the if statement  go back to the inner loop(for x in tables) after it  executes the print '   ' in the else part of if statement. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Did you try `break`?

Comment: What you want seems quite unclear, do you want to exit the inner loop in the case it executes "print '  ' " ?

Comment: yeah and go back to the for x in tableau part

Comment: You should explain what is the attended result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 for y in range(0,5):      
 print '\n'
 for x in tableau:
      if y < len(x):
       print x[y],
      else :
          print '   '
          break
```

Will break out of the inner for and back into the outer for, after the print is executed. This will print a "\n" and then move back to the inner for, which I believe is what you are asking?

Answer (score 1):

As I don't really understand what you need, I suggest you 2 solutions
First one: print '   ' instead of inexistent list element (3 times if len(x) == 2)

```
for x in tableau:
    print '\n'
    for y in x:
        print y
    for y in range(5 - len(x))
        print '   '
```

Second one: print '   ' always at the end of the list

```
for x in tableau:
    print '\n'
    for y in x:
        print y
    print '   '
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Delgan, the answer is staightforward - you have to use the `break` keyword :

```
 for y in range(0,5):      
     print '\n'
     for x in tableau:
          if y < len(x):
           print x[y],
          else :
              print '   ' 
              break
```

The break keyword exits the most inner loop.